# Punctuate a clause-example-clause-example in a sentence

Tags: grammar, sentence, dashes

I'm proofreading a colleagues work, and ran across a sentence which contains two examples with clarifications. I do not believe this should be broken out into two sentences.

The original (nouns changed to protect the innocent):

> In this way, all Jabberwockies have a "foo", meaning the bar associated with that foo, and a "fizz", meaning the buzz of where the Jabberwocky is.

I believe this would benefit from an em-dash, but the comma between the two "parts" of this sentence seem off:

> In this way, all Jabberwockies have a "foo" - meaning the bar associated with that foo, and a "fizz" - meaning the buzz of where the Jabberwocky is.

Is this second version the best way to portray the sentence?

Comment: In a technical context, I would unhesitatingly put both those "clarifying clauses" in ***brackets***.

Comment: Informally, I'd put them in parentheses.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Why brackets and not parenthesis?

Comment: @ Erik: Same as most people, I call (these things) [***brackets***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/brackets). Obviously the *round* ones are often called ***parentheses*** in a grammar/orthography context, but that term can also be applied to [***the text contained within the delimiters***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/parenthesis) (which delimiters might be dashes, commas, etc.), so I was trying to avoid potential confusion. (Which didn't work for you or keshlam, obviously! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt there's one definite "best" method for sentences like this. But I'd recommend using **parentheses** to minimize ambiguity and give each clause a clear beginning and end. (In your original revision, it could be a little difficult to keep track of which clause references which example.)

> In this way, all Jabberwockies have a "foo" (meaning the bar associated with that foo) and a "fizz" (the buzz at the Jabberwocky's location).

By placing the brackets directly after each word in quotations, it should be immediately clear between information describing "Foo" and information describing "Fizz".

---

If all else fails, you can always rearrange the structure into *clause-clause-example-example* format:

> In this way, all Jabberwockies have a "foo" and a "fizz" - where "foo" means the person pitied by Mr. T, and "fizz" is in reference to the Jabberwocky's favorite beverage.